# How does Visual Studio determine which process template to use when creating a project in VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have a VSTS account for which the default process template is set to "Agile".

Looking at my projects, it seems that the ones that were created through the web interface are set to "Agile", but the ones that were created by clicking the "Publish to VSTS" button in Visual Studio Team Explorer are all set to "Scrum".

I can't find a setting anywhere in Visual Studio - and there are many settings - that looks as if it might influence this behaviour.

As noted elsewhere ([Visual Studio Team Services: How to migrate from Agile to Scrum process template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052478/visual-studio-team-services-how-to-migrate-from-agile-to-scrum-process-template)), changing process template once a project has been created is a non-trivial task, and certainly not one I'd like to undertake in this particular context, which is that of a conference talk.

Comment: Why not create the project first and add your source code to it.

Comment: I realise I can do that from the web interface, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it from Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug which will be addressed in a future update, I will attempt to add to this answer then. (Source: https://twitter.com/DonovanBrown/status/955889345755480064)