# How to change process for a project in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Fcustomize%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Fcustomize%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts#change-the-process-used-by-a-project and I deleted ALL work items in my existing Scrum project. Now I want to switch it to use Agile process, but the option in the endpoint visualstudio.com/_settings/process?_a=all is presenting a dialog box saying "There are currently no projects available to change to the Agile process."

Had anyone achieved it before?

Comment: You can't change from Scrum to Agile, you only can change from Agile to another process based on Agile (or from Scrum to based scrum process).

Comment: :O thats bad for me, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shayki Abramczyk is right, we can not change from Scrum to Agile directly, cross processes is not supported (Agile, Scrum, CMMI).

However as a workaround you can try to migrate the project from Scrum to Agile：

1. Create a new team project based on the Agile process
2. Clone the repository (For Git, you can directly Import the
   repository, see [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts) and [Import repositories from
   TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc?view=vsts))
3. Export and import the work items from previous Scrum team project to
   the new created Agile team project. (It maybe loss some information
   for the work items, reference this thread for details:
   [Visual Studio Team Services: How to migrate from Agile to Scrum process template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052478/visual-studio-team-services-how-to-migrate-from-agile-to-scrum-process-template)