# TFS 2017 move TFS source code repository to new instance of TFS

Tags: tfs

We installed the free version of TFS 2017 and created a new project. We now have source code with history. The PM decided they wanted to switch from Agile to Scrum so a lot of commands were run to try to do this. These commands came from a blog found on the internet. The supervisor then decided that it should NOT have been switched to scrum and said we needed to switch back to Agile. So similar commands were run to try to do that. Now the Project Management portion of our project is broken. We can't run queries and the work items are corrupted. I want to try to just install a new instance of free TFS 2017 and copy/move the source code (TFS, NOT GIT) to the new instance and start over with the PM stuff. Can we do this or is it a lost cause.

Comment: You can always get your current project template fixed. Just download latest agile project template available in you TFS instance, Then import all work item definitions and the process configuration and you would be back in operation with your current team project.

Comment: This is what we did to get from Scrum back to Agile and corrupted things. From comment below by PatrickLu you cannot go from Scrum to Agile.. I would include the script that did the imports but it is long.

Comment: Since your original project is created as agile it can always be fixed as an agile template... agree it cannot convert to scrum... but you can get it fixed as agile template

Comment: No. I tried running imports of the latest Agile templates but it did not do anything. We still cannot run queries etc. I am still unclear how to move Source Code WITH history/changesets to a new Project Collection/Project. I don't care about any Feature/Epic/Work items etc since we can recreate those. This is TFS Server 2017 free version on a standalone VM. This is not VSTS. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually we do not suggest OPs to do the process template change in a single team project. Take a look at this MS documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/manage-process#change-the-process-used-by-team-projects)) ...

> You can change the process a team project uses from a system process
>   or inherited process to an inherited process. You can only change team
>   projects to use another process that inherits from the same system
>   process. That is, you can change an Agile-based team project to any
>   process you created from the Agile system process as well as to the
>   Agile process. **Whereas, you can't change a Scrum-based team project to
>   an Agile-derived inherited process.**

There is no need to set up a totally new TFS instance, you could simply **create a new team project based on Agile** and then move your source code and workitems to that new team project.

Since you are not care about the history info about your original team project, it's more easier to achieve this, simply remove your old workspace mapping and map to the new team project.

To move workitems you can export them to Excel, create a new Excel connection to , that is connected to the new team project, and then copy the workitems and pushing them from the new Excel file into the new project.

If you insist on moving the code to new TFS server, you just need to back up your local code and directly check in them as pending changes in the newly created team project on new TFS server.

More details please refer the answer from  *Andrew Clear* in  this similar question: [Visual Studio Team Services: How to migrate from Agile to Scrum process template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052478/visual-studio-team-services-how-to-migrate-from-agile-to-scrum-process-template)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only move Source code from one Team Project Collection to another Team Project Collection, one of the crude workarounds is the following, when you are ONLY requiring SRC code moves.

1. Create a workspace and check out all SRC from the source Team Project in the source TPC.
2. Create a new Team Project in the new TFS instance.
3. Remove the binding files from the SRC dumped out in (1), or better yet just move it on the disk to a new directory and remove all SRC binding files.
4. Then add the source (from the above step 3) into the new Team Project you created in the target TPC you created in (2) above (or it could also be into an existing Team Project you already had in the target TPC).

Once again this is ONLY if you don’t care about the other things such as WITs and Reports from the older Team Project, and you only care about the Source Code.

In addition, you can use the following tool [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/).

Comment: Will this include the Source Code history? It doesn't sound like it. I don't care of PM stuff but I need all Source Code, including history.